# How should I quote this command in a Jenkinsfile to interpret the variables correctly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am having trouble having a command interpret a variable within a declarative Jenkinsfile. In the sample below, it explains how the last command isn't interpreting the variable correctly due to a quoting issue. I am not sure what syntax I need to use. I looked at https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4 and just got more confused.

```
// this works correctly and sets the instance_id variable
script {
  instance_id = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''
    aws autoscaling \
      describe-auto-scaling-groups \
      --auto-scaling-group-names my_asg \
      --query 'AutoScalingGroups[*].Instances[?LifecycleState==`InService`].InstanceId' --output text
  ''').trim()
}

// this also works correctly and show the instance_id was set
echo "getting IP for instance $instance_id"

// this DOES NOT work. What do I need to change here?
// get IP address
script {
  ip_address = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''
    aws ec2 describe-instances \
      --query "Reservations[*].Instances[?InstanceId=='$instance_id'].PrivateIpAddress" \
      --output text
  ''').trim()
}
```

When the last command runs, it outputs this, showing that it isn't interpreting the instance_id variable:

`+ aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[?InstanceId=='\'''\''].PrivateIpAddress' --output text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last example doesn't work because you are using triple single-quotation marks for the script:

```groovy
 ip_address = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '''
```

Use triple double-quotation marks instead:

```groovy
ip_address = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """
  aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --query "Reservations[*].Instances[?InstanceId=='$instance_id'].PrivateIpAddress" \
    --output text
""").trim()
```

Note that you don't have to escape single double-quotation marks within the script, but you would have to escape `$` as `\$` if you want to refer to a shell variable.

Further reading: [Groovy - String Interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation)